# Android Studio Issue - Premature end of file

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 0.2.6 in Mac Mountain Lion. When I run the project first time, it runs fine.

But next time onwards, I have the following error:

```
Internal error: (org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException) Error on line 1: Premature end of file.
org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1: Premature end of file.
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:533)
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:946)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadDocument(JDOMUtil.java:377)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadDocument(JDOMUtil.java:355)
at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadRootElement(JpsLoaderBase.java:69)
at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadRootElement(JpsLoaderBase.java:40)
at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadFromDirectory(JpsProjectLoader.java:127)
at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:99)
at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:41)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:45)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:71)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:198)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:113)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:128)
at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:174)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:388)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1427)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1056)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:518)
... 20 more
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:174)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:388)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1427)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1056)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:518)
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:946)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadDocument(JDOMUtil.java:377)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadDocument(JDOMUtil.java:355)
at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadRootElement(JpsLoaderBase.java:69)
at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadRootElement(JpsLoaderBase.java:40)
at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadFromDirectory(JpsProjectLoader.java:127)
at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:99)
at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:41)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:45)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:71)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:198)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:113)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:128)
at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

I've tried restarting, reverting files from SVN, deleting out and gen folders and rebuiding. But still not working. It drives me crazy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you getting an alert of Deprecation code and if yes, then are u fixing it ?

Comment: no alert of deprecation..

Comment: okay then, may be you should check in ModuleSetting (F12) and check all the 'dependencies'. Their scope should be "Compile" and not "Provided"

Answer (score 14):

None of the above worked for me. Thinking it may involve the beta 5.1 version of AndroidStudio I even reverted to a previous stable version but no luck.

The solution for me was to do a file search for all XML files in the project, sort them by size, and find the two empty XML files that should have been deleted but were only truncated to zero size. It was then a simple matter of deleting them. After that everything went well.

I hope that saves some folks the 2 hours or so of hair pulling I went through. I sure wish the stack trace printing also included the names of the problematic files. That would have saved a lot of aggravation.

Comment: This was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: You can find the faulty file name in the log now. Deleted the file it works fine.

Comment: in my case it was empty drawable

Answer (score 8):

just Delete .idea directory and app.iml file and then import project again and it will generate new Gradle file and your problem resolve....

Comment: Please don't consider this answer, it will damage your project if you have no backup.

Answer (score 4):

This happened when I checked out the project in another computer and then back to the first one.

I fixed the problem by closing the project and then `File > Import Project...` from the exect same sources.

Android Studio fixed the project while keeping all previous gradle configurations.

It drove me crazy too :)

Answer (score 3):

For me a simple *Build -> Clean Project* and then rebuilding did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems fixed when creating new projects in 0.8.1.  Unfortunately, if you created the project on a version less than 0.8.1, and then try to open with the new version, you still get the same error. I had to create a whole new project from scratch with 0.8.1 to no longer get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all folder from this folder directory link :C:\Users\BeingXpert.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar

Its solve my problem which is same!

Answer (score 0):

I just did

> File->Invalidate Caches and Restart

It solved the error

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a problem with the project. As I was also getting the same issue on opening a project and after applying almost all of the solution above I concluded that none of them worked for me. So I decided to create a new project and I got the same problem in the freshly created project too. Then I came to know that this issue wasn't with my project it was an issue something in Android Studio. So, What steps I took to solve the issue were:

1. Go to User Directory i.e C:\users\%your user name%\
2. Delete .idea and .Android directory
3. Open Android Studio and when it asks for import settings, select "Do not import settings" option.

Tested on Android Studio 3.6.2.